# In the metadata, where is the record page layout used in a Lightning Record Page/Flexipage defined?

Tags: page-layout, metadata, flexipages

I have a Lightning Record page that has a section with a case page layout. When I retrieve the metadata for the Flexipage, the markup for the section with the page layout looks like this:

```
<flexiPageRegions>
    <componentInstances>
       <componentName>force:detailPanel</componentName>
    </componentInstances>
    <name>main</name>
    <type>Region</type>
</flexiPageRegions>
```

Where is the layout used in this section defined? I did a find across files for the layout name and can't find anything that looks promising. Does it perhaps inherit from an org setting somewhere - does setting the layout used have to be a manual step (this is a valid answer, but looking for confirmation)?

Comment: Did you see the documentation [flexiPageRegions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm)?

Comment: @RahulSharma I have - it appears there's not a field defined on that to specify the specific layout. I would be happy to be wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force:detailPanel component is showing the layout as defined by the page layout. See [Page Layouts (help)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layout.htm&type=5) and [Layout (Metadata API)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm).

Also when you select the component in Lightning App Builder the right hand side section has more info and links to the specific page layouts used.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question - in the OP, the `force:detailPage`  shows no such definition. I'd love to accept an answer here, but please elaborate

Comment: Yes, there is no property or anything you configure on force:detailPage to map this. It is all internal to force:detailPage. What layout it shows is determined by the page layout assignment, which you can read more how to configure here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutassign.htm&type=5

Comment: Does the `force:detailPanel` work for Custom Objects? It gives error when I use a custom Object say-  `<force:detailPanel aura:id="myCustomObject" entityApiName='MyCustomObject__c' />` but works fine with  `<force:detailPanel aura:id="case" entityApiName='Case' />`. Error I get is - `You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access`

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon it looking for something else but it seems it has not been answered yet.

The page layout assignments per profile and record type are defined in the profile. If you using MDAPI/SFDX to retrieve the profile, keep in mind only the assignments related to the layouts and record types that are retrieved together with the profile will be retrieved, so you need to be careful with how you manage and deploy profile data between the orgs.